# error while copying mapping and setting of elasticsearch index of version 5.1 to 7.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to copy the whole index data from a remote server to my local elasticsearch.

As per [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote), to use _reindex, we have to first copy the mapping and setting of source index

on running curl -XGET x.x.x.x:9200/modified_taxonomy/ and the result gave me the mapping and setting of the index

```
{ "mappings": {"keywords": {"properties": {"Commodities": {"properties": {"Code": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "Title": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "code": {"type": "long"}, "title": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } } } }, "Keyword": {"type": "text", "fields": {"analyzed": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword", "search_analyzer": "analyzer_shingle"}, "keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }, "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword", "search_analyzer": "analyzer_shingle"}, "KeywordType": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "Occupations": {"properties": {"Code": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "Title": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "code": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "title": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } } } }, "Source": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "from": {"type": "long"}, "query": {"properties": {"bool": {"properties": {"must": {"properties": {"match_all": {"type": "object"} } } } }, "match": {"properties": {"Keyword": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } } } } } }, "scroll": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "scroll_id": {"type": "text", "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } } }, "size": {"type": "long"} } } }, "settings": {"index": {"number_of_shards": "5", "blocks": {"write": "false"}, "analysis": {"filter": {"my_shingle_filter": {"max_shingle_size": "8", "min_shingle_size": "2", "output_unigrams": "true", "type": "shingle"} }, "analyzer": {"analyzer_keyword": {"filter": ["lowercase"], "char_filter": ["code_mapping"], "type": "custom", "tokenizer": "keyword"}, "analyzer_shingle": {"filter": ["lowercase", "my_shingle_filter"], "char_filter": ["code_mapping"], "tokenizer": "standard"} }, "char_filter": {"code_mapping": {"type": "mapping", "mappings": ["++ => plusplus", "c# => csharp", "C# => csharp", "F# => fsharp", "f# => fsharp", ".net => dotnet", ".Net => dotnet", ".NET => dotnet", "( => map_lp", ") => map_rp", "& => and", "# => hash", "+ => plus"] } } }, "number_of_replicas": "2"} } }
```

so i tried to curl -XPUT localhost:9200/mytaxonomy/  using the above json.

It gave me a error index not available. so I created the index curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/taxomony_1 and tried to repeat the procedure.

It gave me an error

```
{"error": {"root_cause": [{"type": "illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "In Shingle TokenFilter the difference between max_shingle_size and min_shingle_size (and +1 if outputting unigrams) must be less than or equal to: [3] but was [7]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_shingle_diff] index level setting."} ], "type": "illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "In Shingle TokenFilter the difference between max_shingle_size and min_shingle_size (and +1 if outputting unigrams) must be less than or equal to: [3] but was [7]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_shingle_diff] index level setting."}, "status": 400 }
```

though I have changed the "max_shingle_size": 2 and "min_shingle_size":2 , it gives me error  again,

```
{"error": {"root_cause": [{"type": "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [keywords : {properties={KeywordType={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Keyword={search_analyzer=analyzer_shingle, analyzer=analyzer_keyword, type=text, fields={analyzed={search_analyzer=analyzer_shingle, analyzer=analyzer_keyword, type=text}, keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, size={type=long}, Occupations={properties={code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}, Commodities={properties={code={type=long}, Title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}, query={properties={bool={properties={must={properties={match_all={type=object}}}}}, match={properties={Keyword={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}}}, scroll={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, from={type=long}, scroll_id={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Source={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}]"} ], "type": "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [keywords : {properties={KeywordType={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Keyword={search_analyzer=analyzer_shingle, analyzer=analyzer_keyword, type=text, fields={analyzed={search_analyzer=analyzer_shingle, analyzer=analyzer_keyword, type=text}, keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, size={type=long}, Occupations={properties={code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}, Commodities={properties={code={type=long}, Title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}, query={properties={bool={properties={must={properties={match_all={type=object}}}}}, match={properties={Keyword={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}}}, scroll={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, from={type=long}, scroll_id={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Source={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}]", "caused_by": {"type": "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [keywords : {properties={KeywordType={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Keyword={search_analyzer=analyzer_shingle, analyzer=analyzer_keyword, type=text, fields={analyzed={search_analyzer=analyzer_shingle, analyzer=analyzer_keyword, type=text}, keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, size={type=long}, Occupations={properties={code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}, Commodities={properties={code={type=long}, Title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, title={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Code={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}, query={properties={bool={properties={must={properties={match_all={type=object}}}}}, match={properties={Keyword={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}}}, scroll={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, from={type=long}, scroll_id={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, Source={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}]"} }, "status": 400 }
```

Though I didnt modify any thing the mapping of the source it gives me unsupported parameters. what could be the issue? how to copy the setting and mapping of the source index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i think its because in elastic 7 remove type feature and for re indexing you need to have same version and bigger cluster to work i think you need logstash or some script to copy your data

> You must use the same size or larger cluster, and the same
>   Elasticsearch version. Depending on your security settings for your
>   old cluster,

Comment: Yes, there is version difference, the one which i am trying to copy is version 5.1.1 and newly installed version is 7.4. should i remove type features in properties or across all json ?

Comment: how can i modify the mapping and settings ? I have removed all type feature in the json and tried to "put". but still i have the same error "mapper_parsing_exception"